# Count number of files in input box with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, count

How can I count the number of files that are in the file upload input using jQuery?

I have tried this but it always returns 1:

```
$("body").on("change", ".create-album .custom-file-input .createAlbumFileUpload", function(){   

    var numFiles = $("input:file", this).length;
    alert(numFiles);
});
```

My HTML:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="createAlbumFileUpload">
    <input type="file" name="uploadFile[]" multiple="multiple"/>
</form>
```

I found this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ShankarSangoli/yQFXq/) on another question asking the same thing, however I can't see why mine isn't working?

Comment: Yours doesn't look at the files of the input in the same way that the fiddle does.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The fiddle you provided contains the answer.

```
var numFiles = $("input:file", this)[0].files.length;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xvLAc/1/

Comment: Ah that is odd. You did remove the extra selectors didn't you?

Answer (score 1):

You can also try with this,

Take the input in Div and give an id,

```
var count =  $('#divPhoto').children().length; // You'll get the length in this.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily check with below code and https://jsfiddle.net/vvz3a4qp/2/ :

HTML:

```
<form name="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="file" name="name1" >
<input type="file" name="name2" ><br><br>
<span id="total"></span>
</form>
```

JS:

```
 $("body").change(function(){
            alert($(":file").length);
            $("#total").html($("input[type=file]").length);
      });
```